# Realm Javascript creates objects but returns empty object

Tags: javascript, realm

I have an existing React Native application using Realm for local data. This has worked for several years. I have now upgraded to Realm 6.0.4.

My realm is defined as follows:

```
const Store = {
    name: 'Store',
    properties: {
        storeId: {type: 'int'},
        storeName: {type: 'string'}
    }
};

export default new Realm({schema: [Store], schemaVersion: 20});
```

I write data to it as follows:

```
 realm.write(() => {
     realm.create('Stores', {storeId: 1, storeName: "My Store"});
 });
```

I try to read as follows:

```
 let stores = realm.objects('Stores'))
```

And I always get the data as empty objects:

```
[{}]
```

Even though the count of objects is correct.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on that `realm.objects` function call and stepping through that with a debugger?

Comment: If I extract the database and open it in Realm studio the data is there. The count of objects returned is also correct but they're empty {}.  I don't think I can step into to that from React Native?

Comment: Yep spent days looking at this. Realm clearly is broken (or I am). :x

Comment: I found that if you iterate the ```realm.objects``` you get the instances of the objects stored on the database

Comment: Any changes here? How is that possible?